Get games between members of a team with Lichess API
I would like for stats reasons to get all the games played between members of a same team. Is there a way with a direct call to the API ?

no there is no direct way but you have https://lichess.org/api#tag/Games/operation/apiGamesUser  (use with vs parameter)  and you can get the team members of a team using api https://lichess.org/api#tag/Teams/operation/teamIdUsers. so basically you'll have to do a little bit of coding

Yes, I was arrived to the same point and so need to code to extract a string composed from users Id separated with comma but  to set the "players" parameter and not the vs one if I'm right.

If you come up with some kind of solution it might be nice to share - in history this could have helped me. Only if you want to, of course!

I will do it as soon as I will have a working solution. I'm working with Electron but I've stopped developping for some time so little bit rusted

@AlainBUFERNE so I assume you're looking for a JavaScript/node implementation?

yes I will work with Javascript. I realized this morning that I was wrong conerning the players parameter which is only used for pgn modification. I'm now more oriented toward a solution where I will download team'smembers data periodically in a database and will work on this small extracted database locally which is far enough for what I need where a pseudo real time is not necesary at all. Besides it will be better for Lichess server load.

I’m voting to close this question because this is more of a programming problem (suited for stackoverflow, or other sites), but not a chess problem.

@bakunin "Chess-specific questions about programming ...other chess software are welcome" (source).
